# Django: problem of displaying uploaded images

Tags: python, django, image

I'm building a photo blog via Django, it has a very basic structure:
1)a list page: each post has a cover picture
2)severals detail pages correspondant: each page contains multiple pictures.
At the list page, things are all good, the cover picture displayed correctely, but for the detail web page, the pictures that I uploaded from django admin won't show up, though they can be found in the local folder \media. I checked the page in Chrome, I got this: <img src(unknown) alt>. I'm confused.
Thanks a lot for your time and help.

[image]
[image]

structure :

```
lyv_dev #project name
    --settings.py
    --urls.py
media
    --upload1.jpg
    --upload2.jpg
    --upload3.jpg
    -- ...
project #app name
    -- templates
       --projects
         -- base.html
         -- list.html
         -- detail.html
    -- urls.py
    -- admin.py
    -- views.py
static
    -- css
       -- style.css
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# models project
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique_for_date = 'publish')
    text = models.TextField()
    year = models.IntegerField(default = 2020)
# couv: this is a cover picture
    couv = models.FileField(blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    weidth = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('projects:project_detail', args=[self.slug])

# Images related with project
class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='projectimages')
    images = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project, ProjectImage

class ProjectImageAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProjectImage

@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'publish')
    search_fields = ('title', 'text')
    prepopulated_fields =  {'slug':('title',)}
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ('status', 'publish')
    inlines = [ProjectImageAdmin]

    class Meta:
        model = Project
   
@admin.register(ProjectImage)
class PostImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py (in django project folder)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projects.urls', namespace='projects')), 
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py (in django app folder)

```
  from django.urls import path
    from .import views
    from .views import ProjectLisView
    
    app_name = 'projects'
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', ProjectLisView.as_view(), name='projects_list'),
        path('projects/<slug:project>/', views.project_detail, name='project_detail'), 
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Project, ProjectImage
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ProjectLisView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'projects'


def project_detail(request, project):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=project, status='published')
    images = project.projectimages.all()
    return render(request, 'projects/detail.html', {'project':project, 'images':images})
```

list.html

```
{% extends "projects/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for project in projects %}
        <p class="title"><a href="{{ project.get_absolute_url }}">{{project.title}}</a></p>
        <div><img src="{{ project.couv.url }}" alt=""></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "projects/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>this is a detail page</p>
    {{ project.title }}
    {{ project.year }}
    <p>{{ project.width }} x {{ project.height }} mm </p>
    {% for image in images %}
    <div><img src="{{ images.url }}" alt=""></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
            <section class="content">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know where `(unknown)` comes from but instead of `{{ images.url }}` you need to be writing `{{ image.images.url }}`. (Quite a misnomer of a field name `images` when it is only **one** image..)

Comment: wow! thanks a bunch ! I changed the url as you said. it worked. But i m not sure where the magical singular "image" comes from. When you said "only one image", did you mean "only one image" in the <img src ="" > ?

Comment: That `image` is from the loop you have written yourself in the line just above... When I said it is just one image I meant the `FileField` which is named as `images` (Also this should be an `ImageField` if this stores an image really...)

Comment: Yeah, I think i see what you mean. Thanks again, I would've been stuck for hours.